# Pass concatenated string to server with AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

I don't know how to end this line of code:

```
xhttp.open("GET", "server.php?width=" + w + "&height=" + h ???, true);
```

I guess there must be a `"` at the question marks, but how do I end it? I tried all kinds of combinations, but non of them works?

Comment: it should just be `xhttp.open("GET", "server.php?width=" + w + "&height=" + h , true );` with nothing after `h`

Comment: Remove the question marks and you're done. String concatenation is JavaScript basics. It's unrelated to Ajax and doesn't suddenly change when Ajax is involved. When in doubt, make a variable first: `var url = "server.php?width=" + w + "&height=" + h; xhttp.open("GET", url, true);`.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
xhttp.open("GET", "server.php?width=" + w + "&height=" + h, true);
```

This should be your answer.

In such scenario, you should always put this in a variable and use that variable in function.

The best way would be -

```
var postDimensions = "server.php?width=" + w + "&height=" + h;
```

`xhttp.open("GET", postDimensions , true`);

In this way, you won't need to touch AJAX request. You will modify the variable if you want to make any changes in path.